# Como usar onload em elementos DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou definido algumas funções semelhantes para páginas diferentes em um site. Logo, estas funções ficam num mesmo arquivo. Quando o arquivo JS é carregado as funções `$(function() { /*function1*/ });` e `$(function() { /*function2*/ });` são executadas. Porém, os elementos os quais eu pego via jQuery (Ex.: `$('.elem').val();`) não existirão, pois estão em outra página.

**Como faço uma função executar apenas quando um determinando elemento estiver carregado?**

Comment: poderia postar o comando que esta chamando essas funções?

Comment: Existem maneiras diferentes consoante a maneira como os elementos são adicionados. Pode esclarecer como "aparecem" na página esse `$('.elem')`?

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de saber se um elemento existe com jQuery é usar a propriedade length. `$('.elem').length` te diz quantos elementos tem na página que correspondem ao seletor `.elem`.

```
if( $('.elem').length > 0 ){
   //tem nós da classe elem no documento
}else{
   //nao tem
}
```

Comment: Gambiarra Lv. Asiático, mas funciona! XD

Comment: Eh, nem é tão gambiarra assim... é a forma mais comum que as pessoas usam pra testar se um elemento existe usando jquery.

Comment: Sério? Caramba!!! Acho que é uma coisa um tanto comum esse meu problema. Pensei que existisse uma solução mais direta.

Answer (score 1):

dependendo das operações que deseja fazer com o(s) elemento(s), o ideal é utilizar o $.each pois assim você consegue referenciar cada um deles com o $(this) ou com as variáveis dos parâmetros.

**Ex:**

```
$(".layout_cron").each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(this).data("elemento")) elemento = $(this).data("elemento"); else elemento = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
    cronometro_regressivo($(this).data("agora"), $(this).data("fim"), elemento);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="header_banner_cron" class="layout_cron" data-agora="1407032260" data-fim="1407553140" style="position:absolute;left:197px;top:0px;"></div>
```